# How to predict the color of a pH indicator using Le Chatelier's principle

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium, ph

[image: Question regarding predicting the color of pH indicator in different solutions]

The question I have is above. Could someone explain why the answer is (A)?

What I think so far:

- Does the sodium hydroxide turn the indicator blue because it is a strong base and hence it will react completely to form water,
  shifting equilibrium really far to the right?
- Does the HCl turn the indicator red for a similar reason?
- I am unsure of the sodium acetate effect

Comment: Please note that the [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) on this site requires you 
to **show some personal effort**.

Comment: I've added some of my attempts on the question? Could you please help?

Comment: IMHO, the equations in the question have been incorrectly written. This is not chemistry, it's rather confusing and playing mean tricks on students. In the alkaline, H3O+ does not exist. It should read H2Z + OH- <--> HZ- + H2O etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You're absolutely on the right track!**

The keys to the question are

1. to  order $\ce{HCl}$, $\ce{NH4Cl}$, $\ce{NaOAc}$ and $\ce{NaOH}$ in terms of strong acid, weak acid, weak base and strong base
2. to realize that in the presence of $\ce{HCl}$, the indicator exists as $\ce{H2Z}$, while it is fully deprotonated to $\ce{Z^{2-}}$ in the presence of $\ce{NaOH}$
3. in the presence of weak acids or weak bases, the indicator exists in form of each two species. Consequently, a mixed colour is observed.

In the presence of $\ce{NaOAc}$, a weak base, $\ce{H2Y}$ is completely deprotonated, thus no red colour is observed. In addition, a **part** of $\ce{HY-}$ is deprotonated too: the second equilibrium isn't completely on the left side. **Some amount** of $\ce{Y^{2-}}$ is present too. As a result, the green colour (yellow + blue) is observed.

It is all about the position of the equilibria.

Comment: Alright! I understand points 1 and 2, but why does the indicator exist as two species in the presence of weak base? I think I may have some sort of idea, but I would prefer it if you gave a definite explanation. Thankyou!

Comment: @chemistryyo I've tried to address the last point too.

Comment: Sorry, I just have another question:
How do we know that H2Y is completely deprotonated. If this was a single equilibrium reaction, there should be some H2Y present